# iOS: setting image for UIImageView from a loaded image with correct scale factor for retina displays

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, scale, retina-display

I'm working on iOS devices with retina displays. Basically, I have a `UIImageView` and set its image by loading a jpeg image in the **documents folder**.

Let's say, the `UIImageView` has a size 100x100 points. And the jpeg image has dimensions of 200x200 pixels. As far as I understand, the jpeg image should be viewed in the `UIImageView` without any scaling. I read the jpeg image as

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];            
NSString *jpegFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/im_%d_%d.jpeg",docDir, dbPhotoId, i];
UIImage* tmpImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", jpegFilePath]];
```

the `UIImage* tmpImage` has a scale factor of 1 and width and height of 200 and 200 (observed from `tmpImage.scale`, `tmpImage.size.width` and `tmpImage.size.height`).

In this case, if I set the image property of the `UIImageView` (with dimensions 100x100 points) as the `tmpImage`, can I safely assume that there won't be any scaling or retina display problems ?

Comment: You can never safely assume anything. Always test!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the value of `contentMode` property of the image view. If the value is `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` the image will look good on retina displays but this isn't the right way to do it.

It's better to have two version of your images, one for normal display and the other for retina as explained [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html).

Comment: In my specific application, the loaded jpeg images are only the ones that are saved for captured photos. Therefore, the images will be used either always for retina or always for non-retina display. In this case, I think there is no need to save two versions of the image. So follow-up question is: For the only-retina scenario, is it better to save the image with @2x modifier? or it doesn't make a difference?

Comment: Yes, I think it's better to save the image with @2x modifier so you don't worry about the size. Or you can create a new `UIImage` from the image you have by calling `initWithCGImage:scale:orientation:` and pass `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` as the scale value.

Comment: Is it better due to cleaner/easier code design or is it better so that in this way the performance (for example, computations for rendering the image) would be better?